# How to change dbid in oracle to specific value?

Tags: oracle, database-design, backup

I want to change dbid of oracle 11g database.
Current dbid = **2241883xxx**   And
want to set dbid = **1380515xxx**

Comment: Why do you need it? You can use `set dbid` command in rman, but this will apply only for a session. This is usually needed for cross-site restores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no officially published method for this and it is not documented, but still possible, with `DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE`. Here is an example:

[http://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-choose-your-oracle-database-id-dbid/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627020445/https://pythian.com/blog/how-to-choose-your-oracle-database-id-dbid/)

Comment: I’m restoring Prod Oracle db backup to DR db.
Both Prodb & DR servers (Win 2008R2) have identical Oracle (11g) db settings, db file location and db instance names.

In order to get successful restore to DR Oracle server, DBID of DR server should be same as Production server. I have been trying to change DBID of DR server, but it is not changing
I have run following commands on Oracle DR to change DBID:

SQL>shutdown immediate;
SQL>startup nomount;

RMAN>set DBID=2241883xxx;

The O/p of set DBID= 2241883xxx, is below:
executing command: SET DBID 
when I go back to SQL> prompt Its can't changed.

Comment: AFAIK the order should be `execute rman; set dbid; connect target / catalog ...; restore controlfile; startup mount;`. The DBID must not be read from controlfile.

Comment: the new url is https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-choose-your-oracle-database-id-dbid/

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using the nid command to change the dbid to a new value. then register your database with the rman catalog, if you use one.

```
nid help=y

DBNEWID: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Wed Oct 7 13:56:42 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Keyword     Description                    (Default)
----------------------------------------------------
TARGET      Username/Password              (NONE)
DBNAME      New database name              (NONE)
LOGFILE     Output Log                     (NONE)
REVERT      Revert failed change           NO
SETNAME     Set a new database name only   NO
APPEND      Append to output log           NO
HELP        Displays these messages        NO
```